# Paypal SDK giving error when trying to create Payment

Tags: paypal, sdk, paypal-sandbox

I created an app on PayPal with sandbox account. Then i picked up its API Client id and Secret.
I created a new console application and added paypal nuget package version 1.9.1.

```
 internal class Program { static void Main(string[] args) { // Get a reference to the config var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

        // Use OAuthTokenCredential to request an access token from PayPal
        var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config["clientId"], config["clientSecret"]);

        var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken.GetAccessToken());


        try
        {

            var payment = new Payment()
            {
                intent = "authorize",
                // A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment. Use the List of `FundingInstrument` and the Payment Method as 'credit_card'
                payer = new Payer()
                {
                    // The Payment creation API requires a list of
                    // FundingInstrument; add the created `FundingInstrument`
                    // to a List
                    funding_instruments = new List<FundingInstrument>()
                {
                    // A resource representing a Payeer's funding instrument.
                    // Use a Payer ID (A unique identifier of the payer generated
                    // and provided by the facilitator. This is required when
                    // creating or using a tokenized funding instrument)
                    // and the `CreditCardDetails`
                    new FundingInstrument()
                    {
                        // A resource representing a credit card that can be used to fund a payment.
                        credit_card = new CreditCard()
                        {
                            billing_address = new Address()
                            {
                                city = "Johnstown",
                                country_code = "US",
                                line1 = "52 N Main ST",
                                postal_code = "43210",
                                state = "OH"
                            },
                            cvv2 = "874",
                            expire_month = 11,
                            expire_year = 2023,
                            first_name = "Joe",
                            last_name = "Shopper",
                            number = "5105105105105100",
                            type = "visa"
                        }
                    }
                },
                    payment_method = "credit_card"
                },
                // The Payment creation API requires a list of transactions; add the created `Transaction` to a List
                transactions = new List<Transaction>()
            {
                // A transaction defines the contract of a payment - what is the payment for and who is fulfilling it. Transaction is created with a `Payee` and `Amount` types
                new Transaction()
                {
                    // Let's you specify a payment amount.
                    amount = new Amount()
                    {
                        currency = "USD",
                        // Total must be equal to sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
                        total = "107.47",
                        details = new Details()
                        {
                            shipping = "0.03",
                            subtotal = "107.41",
                            tax = "0.03"
                        }
                    },
                    description = "This is the payment transaction description."
                }
            },
                     payee = new Payee { email = "rassmasood@hotmail.com" }
            };
            var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
       
    }
}
```

Using the code above i get the error mentioned below.

`{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"Invalid request - see details","debug_id":"f3c178cb2a17b","details":[{"field":"/payee","location":"body","issue":"MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON"}],"links":[]}`

is there anything i am doing wrong ?

i tried adding more information to Payee for example its account merchand_id and stuff but didnt worked.

i am expecting the exception to be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal/) you are using [is 5 years old and deprecated](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK).

Use the current [PayPalCheckoutSDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalCheckoutSdk/) 1.0.4

Comment: although might not be relevant but are you sure this is the correct SDK ? it doesnt seem to have any place to capture credit card information. Most relevent thing it has is CaptureRequest which is using PaymentInstruction but it does not have anything about credit card info.

Comment: It is the correct SDK for the standard PayPal Checkout. There is no server-side SDK for processing credit card payments directly. If you want to add an Advanced integration, that is something to be done later, with hosted fields https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/